# Kick off multiple stages across different Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

We have a number of Azure Pipeline stages that we need to be able to choose to kick off, say, in the event of a disaster recovery (DR) situation. We currently have a mix of Classic and YAML pipelines, each with a set of stages that include deployment to a given environment.

Would it be straightforward to deploy a particular stage from each pipeline?

I'm picturing something like a new pipeline that has a series of tasks (maybe in separate jobs or stages) that kick off particular stages in other pipelines. Is this straightforward?

---

Edit for those considering this sort of approach...

**Firing off multiple pipelines has complications:**

- Which version to kick off for each pipeline and how to track that?
- What to do about failures of one or more pipelines?
- What is the rollback strategy?

**If at all possible, change the approach.** Not an easy change, as it may necessitate a design change to the system itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline) tasks to the pipeline to kick off stages in other pipelines.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've had other priorities but have looked some at this extension. We can't use unofficial extensions for something as important as deployments. We may use (and give credit for) some of the code there. However, the more we look at this approach, the more it seems like my question describes a problematic need.